# Definition and difference between a shared array view and a copy of array data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a book that reads, "It is important to know when we are dealing with a shared array view, and when we have a
copy of the array data.", the book however never specifically states what either of those two things are.

Can someone give a very simple explanation what a shared array view is, and what a copy of array data is? And the difference? Can someone explain this using a simple metaphor? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to check is to use numpy's `may_share_memory`:

```
In [11]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [12]: b = a[0:2]

In [13]: c = a.copy()

In [14]: np.may_share_memory(a, b)
Out[14]: True

In [15]: np.may_share_memory(a, c)
Out[15]: False

In [16]: np.may_share_memory(b, c)
Out[16]: False
```

It's important, as assigning to a copy won't affect the original array, whilst changing a view will:

```
In [21]: b[1] = 7

In [22]: a
Out[22]: array([1, 7, 3])

In [23]: c[1] = 11

In [24]: a
Out[24]: array([1, 7, 3])

In [25]: c
Out[25]: array([ 1, 11,  3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Viewing a shared array is referring to an array that is *shared* in memory for multiprocessing vs *having* the actual array data such as a pickle.

[Here](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/1144s75ps4/multiprocessing-shared-memory-vs-pickled-copies) is a link to a conversation going much deeper should you be interested.

Comment: What exactly is an array? Is an array necessarily an image?

Comment: @user3268003 - An array is just a collection of data; `ints`, `floats`, etc. [Link](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/array_object.html#what-are-numpy-and-numpy-arrays)